# polymer elements loading very slowly

Tags: javascript, performance, polymer, paperjs

I wrote up a small polymer project using polymer and paperjs to load an image in a canvas and be able to edit it (and do something further.) The problem currently is that the site is extremely slow to load completely.

Here is the live site - http://sushruta.github.io/

In Firefox, on profiling using firebug, I see that most of the loading of polymer components in synchronous and adds to be a huge 10s. Also, for the initial 2-3 seconds, Firefox goes "Not Responding" and then eventually loads the stuff. I haven't checked it thoroughly in Chrome, but it looks even slower in it.

Is it possible to give me a few pointers as to why the site is so slow? I don't seem to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm working on a project with Polymer 2.0 and have started to realize this as well now. Especially some paper elements like paper-dropdown-menu when having ~10 and each uses template repeaters to generate their content. When I try to profile, there are some methods that takes ~30 seconds to complete, this is really bad.

The Polymer idea is super good but the framework badly needs speed improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Do you [vulcanize](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) your polymer imports ?
If you import many polymer elements make sure you vulcanize them otherwise it will issue a network request for each import and tat is quite slow.

Vulcanize will concat all the polymer element imports into one big file and import this one file.